# how k6 will support for createReadStream property to read file stream

Tags: k6

When I am reading the file from its filepath in typescript. I am getting the error that- Object has no member 'statSync' and Object has no member 'createReadStream'.

```
Below is the code:=
const fs = require('fs');
let filePath:='D:\\Dummy.pdf';
 let streamingInput;
        if (filePath) {
            streamingInput = {
                contentLength: fs.statSync(filePath).size,
                contentType: contentType,
                stream: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            }; 
            return streamingInput;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

k6 is NOT based on nodejs, as such nodejs standard libraries are not supported and you have probably used browserify (as you should) to get it to work in k6. 
But browserify apparently [doesn't support statSync](https://github.com/browserify/brfs/issues/80) or [createReadStream](https://github.com/browserify/brfs/issues/45).

I would suggest you just use k6's [open()](https://docs.k6.io/docs/open-filepath-mode) which will not stream the contents but instead will read them in memory.

Adding a streaming reader is probably a good idea for big files especially given that currently the contents of the file will have a copy for each VU that k6 has as they run a completely separate JS VM. I will be happy if you can [open an issue](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues) about this

Comment: Sorry for late but I want to pass file stream as input to call my api. Can you please sugggest me how to do that?

Comment: What I have suggested with `open()` will have the same effect.
 K6 at this time doesn't support "file stream" whatever you're thinking that is :)